# Looking for a way to select a class based on another item's ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, dom

Ok, so i have a few divs which each have 2 classes, one that is the same for all of them, and one that refers to the ID of another div. The idea is that when the parent div is clicked, i do things to the div's whose class ( a number) is identical to the clicked div's ID. But since i can't know the number in advance (Created by Wordpress through a page ID), i am having trouble figuring out how to target the div's in question. I am not super experienced, so please be patient if it takes a while for me to understand what you mean. :)

```
<div class="somename" id="3">Click me
<div class="divclass 3"> reveal me</div>
</div>
<div class="somename" id="1">Click me 
<div class="divclass 43"> reveal me</div>
<div class="divclass 3"> reveal me</div>
</div>
<div class="somename" id="43">Click me 
<div class="divclass 1"> reveal me</div>
</div>
<div class="somename" id="7">Click me 
<div class="divclass 7"> reveal me</div>
<div class="divclass 7"> reveal me</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch id with `attr` function and supply it to the class selector, Hope this helps

```js
$('div').click(function(e){ 

   $('div').removeClass('active')
   var cl = $(this).attr('id')
   $("."+cl+"").addClass('active')

})
```

```css
.active
{
color:red;
}

.somename
{
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="somename" id="3">Click me </div>
<div class="divclass 3"> reveal me</div>
<div class="somename" id="1">Click me </div>
<div class="divclass 43"> reveal me</div>
<div class="divclass 3"> reveal me</div>
<div class="somename" id="43">Click me </div>
<div class="divclass 1"> reveal me</div>
<div class="somename" id="7">Click me </div>
<div class="divclass 7"> reveal me</div>
<div class="divclass 7"> reveal me</div>
```

Comment: Ok, so i stil have a small issue, and i am trying to figure out what's wrong... It only finds the id for the first div, regardless of whilch one is clicked, and i really don't understand a word of it.. any suggestions to what i may have done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you can read the `id` from the `.somename` elements and use it in a class selector to find the related `.divclass` elements. Try this:

```js
$('.somename').click(function() {
  $('.' + this.id).toggle();
});
```

```css
.divclass {
  display: none;
  color: #888;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="somename" id="3">Click me </div>
<div class="divclass 3"> reveal me</div>
<div class="somename" id="1">Click me </div>
<div class="divclass 43"> reveal me</div>
<div class="divclass 3"> reveal me</div>
<div class="somename" id="43">Click me </div>
<div class="divclass 1"> reveal me</div>
<div class="somename" id="7">Click me </div>
<div class="divclass 7"> reveal me</div>
<div class="divclass 7"> reveal me</div>
```